# Dark background in LibreOffice under Windows

Tags: windows, themes, libreoffice

I hate to write on a white background, so I usually write my papers in a simple text editor, because I can have a dark background, but it's still annoying not to be able to use LibreOffice advanced features.

Is there a real dark background and/or theme for LibreOffice under Windows? I've got the page background to be dark, and text to be white by messing with the styles, however, there is still a bright white margin border. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can modify the application background using the appearance settings (Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice` -> `Appearance`):

[image: modify application background color]

The "Application Background" is the gray area around the sheets, and the "Document Background" setting affects the entire sheet (margins and editable area). Together with the "Font color" setting, you can modify the appearance entirely without altering the document (page / paragraph / character) styles.

Comment: Gosh, I feel stupid, that was so simple! I changed Document background to gray 70% and font color to black, now it's perfect!

Comment: In Libre Office 6.x, the left tree item is not called _Appearance_ anymore, now it's _Application Colors_.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a follow up, I found something you may like too.

Under `Menu Tools -> Personalization` you can now choose a [Firefox theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/) to use for LibreOffice.

Maybe it is worth a look, personally I like it.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version (6.1) this setting has been moved to `Option` → `Application Colors`.

Also, for me, setting `Application background` had no effect.  I had to set `Document background`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since this question was posted, although, I was looking for the same features and found this git very useful: https://github.com/RaitaroH/LibreOffice-BreezeDark

Comment: Do you know how to make it working on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it in Windows (I guess it should work in Windows 10 with the dark theme enabled), but in Linux, if the OS is using a dark background color, you can go to Tools -> Accessibility and check "Automatically detect high contrast mode of operating system".

The background appearance will become dark and the font color will switch to white.

Comment: You should "try it" before you submit an answer.  Please edit your answer, after you "try it", and provide specifics.

Comment: I have tried it.

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 10.

Comment: This is now under Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Accesibility in my LO version on GNU/Linux.